# Как найти слово, начинающееся с определенного символа («@»)?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Например:

```
var str = "Hello @World";
```

Как найти именно слово `World`, т.е. слово, начинающееся с @? Чтобы функция выводила не позицию или не существование символа, а именно слово.

Comment: Приведите полный код, с которым у вас возникли проблемы.

Comment: Может, `str.substr(str.indexOf("@")+1)`? Поясните, в чём проблема вашего подхода.

Comment: Тоесть найти слово начинающийся с вимвола @

Comment: Или найти все такие слова?

Comment: В Chrome можно использовать `str.match(/(?<=@)[\p{L}0-9_]+/gu)` или даже `str.match(/(?<=(?<![\p{L}0-9_])@)[\p{L}0-9_]+/gu)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача не настолько простая, как может показаться на первый взгляд.

Большое значение имеют разрешенные символы в слове после символа `@`.

Ниже пример для цифр и букв латинского алфавита. Если вам нужно расширить данный список, добавляйте его в `[a-z0-9]`.

```js
var tests = [
  // Должно совпадать
  "Hello @World",
  "Hello @World egdfgd",
  "@World",
  "Hello @World hello",
  "Hello @World hgf @hello1",
  "Hello @World @hello2 @trete fgdf@D d",
  // Не должно совпадать
  "Hello @World323^ff hello",
  "Hello @",
  "Hello@World",
  "Hello World",
  "@",
  " @ ",
];
var reg = /\B(@[a-z0-9]+)(\s|$)/ig;
var res = tests.map(f => f.match(reg));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
 var str = "Hello @World";
 var reg = /world/gi;
 console.log(str.match(reg))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var re = /@(\w+)/g;
console.log(re.exec("Hello @World")[1])
```

Для кириллицы

```js
var re = /@([\wа-яА-Я]+)/g;
console.log(re.exec("Привет @Мир")[1])
```

Comment: для кириллицы нужно ещё дописать /ёЁ/, афаир

Comment: @norbornen да, вы правы